# How do I send requests to a private network?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, web, networking

I'm trying to connect to a NodeJS server I wrote in my school network from home so I can work on it. However it's behind a router firewall I have no access to. Is there any way I can make my server accessible from the outside so I can make requests from it?

I was considering some kind of socketed connection where my server tries to "reach out" to my home network every second to establish a link which we can use, but I'm not sure that's feasible or even the best way to go about it.

Comment: Is your computer at home reachable from the internet? meaning, do you have your router set up to put your server in the DMZ or do port forwarding for the ssh port (22) to your machine? If so, then yes you can have your school server establish an ssh tunnel.

Comment: So long as the firewall in-between doesn't block that connection (and you have something reachable in your home network), it would work. That's basically what a reverse shell connection would do.

Comment: There are ways...but consider that any such activity would be bypassing your school's established security protocols, and if discovered would likely get you in trouble. Why not just host the Node server on your machine? Does it need any resources only available in the school's network?

Comment: Yes I have full access to all that in my home network. I'll look into doing exactly that. Thank you

Comment: Yes, I need to access web resources only available on my school network. I'm working on a tool that'd make everyone's lives a little easier and I'd like to work on it from home with the same environment. I have no access to sensitive data anyway and my professors don't mind me doing it if I find a way. I certainly appreciate the concern though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let A be your school server, B your home server, A_user your username on A, and B_user resp. on B.

On B: assuming you are running linux, ensure you have openssh-server installed and running.

On A:

```
ssh -R 10022:localhost:22 B_user@B
```

This establishes an ssh connection to your server at home and open a reverse tunnel. This tunnel means that any connection on B's port 10022 will be forwarded over that first ssh connection to A's port 22 (ssh).

Now on B:

```
ssh -p 10022 A_user@localhost
```

This should give you the idea. In practice, you will find that that ssh tunnel will stop working every once in a while. Once you are ready for it, look at [autossh](https://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) to keep it alive and reestablish it automatically if necessary.